# Use VBA to send mass email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm taking over a workbook created from the last employee. There's a specific coding that I cannot figure out where it states to grab the email list from to plug into the BCC line.
I'm not finding anywhere in the code that states that but the macro somehow works. It is able to extract the email addresses and plug them into the bcc line on the email template. I see that they specified bc_r but I don't see any worksheets name RecipientEmails. The only worksheet with a list of email addresses in this workbook that I see is in the same tab as the command button to pull this email template. The email address is listed on this sheet under column T. So, I'm unsure why the code says c1. Please review the codes below and if you can guide me, I'd appreciate it.

```
Sub esendemail()

    Dim outlook As Object
    Dim newEmail As Object
    Dim xInspect As Object
    Dim pageEditor As Object

    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set newEmail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

    bc_r = ""
    For Each c1 In Range("RecipientEmails")
        bc_r = bc_r & ";" & c1.Value
    Next c1
    
    With newEmail
       
        .To = ""
        .BCC = bc_r
        .Subject = "Welcome to the team!"
        .Body = "[Greetings]" & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & "Practice Name:"
        .Display
        Set xInspect = newEmail.GetInspector
        Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

        Set pageEditor = Nothing
    End With

    Set newEmail = Nothing
    Set outlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: There is a named range (*RecipientEmails*) in your worksheet. `C1` is an iterator variable created in the `For Each` loop that holds the current cell that is being read. My guess is that the named range is the area you see that contains email addresses. See the Name Manager on the Formula panel.

Comment: `Range("RecipientEmails")` is a named range. `Application.Goto Range("RecipientEmails")` will bring you to the range.  Provided that the worksheet isn't hidden.

Answer (score 0):

The email addresses are retrieved in the named range:

```
bc_r = ""
For Each c1 In Range("RecipientEmails")
    bc_r = bc_r & ";" & c1.Value
Next c1
```

Check out the `RecipientEmails` named range in your worksheet. See [Create a named range from selected cells in a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-named-range-from-selected-cells-in-a-worksheet-fd8905ed-1130-4cca-9bb0-ad02b7e594fd) for more information about named ranges.

Also I'd recommend using the `Recipients` property for setting up recipients on the Outlook item. You can read more about that approach in the article I wrote for the technical blog, see [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) for more information.